# using proxy in Angular CLI to redirect http post requests, not redirecting

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I want my requests sent from localhost to be passed to the remote server, I have no control of, by the use of proxy. So that `http://localhost:8000/api/Lists/GetCarList` would be resolved as `https://other-site.ru/api/Lists/GetCarList`
But with my solution, the request is still sent as `http://localhost:8000/api/Lists/GetCarList`

i am running my app with `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --port 8000`

my proxy.conf.json file

```
 {
    "/coreapi/*": {
      "target": "https://other-site.ru",
      "secure": false,
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/": ""
      },
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  }
```

my request

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 
this.oauthService.getAccessToken());    
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');                                       
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers}); 
return this.http.post('/coreapi/UserService/GetUserServersList', {}, options)
 .toPromise().then((response: Response)=>{
    var resp = response;
  },
  err =>{
    console.log("err");
  })
```

So, the question is how to fix this, so that relative requests to `/coreapi/**` be picked up at `https://other-site.ru/coreapi/**`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
"pathRewrite": {"^/coreapi" : "https://other-site.ru/coreapi"}
```

Comment: No it is passing to https://other-site.ru/api/Lists/GetCarList, but I get `Failed to load https://other-site.ru/api/Lists/GetCarList: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.` And if I look at my request there is no Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, thing was that I had to run ng eject and enable cors in generated webpack.config.js file `"devServer": { "historyApiFallback": true, "watchOptions": { "aggregateTimeout": 300, "poll": 1000 }, "headers": { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization" } }`.